# Dynamically Create RecordType in Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex

We have some logic that depends on the record type of a custom object in our managed package. One of our clients has created some custom record types for this SObject - which is throwing an exception.
We've put in a fix, but want to update our unit tests to catch this case as well - so we need to be able to create a new RecordType for this SObject and assign it. However, I cannot figure out how to do this dynamically in Apex.

Tried:

```
insert new RecordType(...);
```

This throws "DML not allowed on RecordType".

According to [SF API](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm|SkinName=webhelp) the RecordType has a "create" method, but:

```
RecordType rt = new RecordType();
rt.DeveloperName = 'Test';
rt.Name = 'Test';
rt.SObjectType = 'Listing__c';
rt.create();
```

Yields "Method does not exist or incorrect signature". Same result when trying as a static method:

```
RecordType.create(rt);
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After discussing with some other SF devs and re-reading the API documentation, it looks like this cannot be done through APEX API (though possible through SOAP API calls).

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_dml_non_dml_objects.htm?SearchType=Stem